# Amazon Connect CTI Adapter: CCP Opens in External Browser Instead of Softphone Layout

Tags: softphone, amazon-connect

I am working on Amazon Connect CTI Adapter and have completed basic configurations. Currently, I am able to make and receive calls as an agent.

When I login to Amazon Connect CTI by clicking "Sign in to CCP" in Phone application in the Utility Bar, Amazon Connect is opening in an external browser window, rather than within the softphone layout. How can I sign in to CCP within the softphone layout?

[image]
[image]